# How to order elements in a list in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an ion-list like this:

```
 <ion-list  *ngFor = "let chat of Chats">
      <ion-item (click) = "openChat(chat.id)">
        <ion-label>
          <h2> {{chat.username}} </h2>
          <p> {{chat.status}}</p>
        </ion-label> 
      </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

I'd like to order my list by "Last modified date" that is present in the attribute chat.lastModified ( the format is 2020-12-30T16:14:26.000+0000), how can I order my list?

Thanks a lot

Comment: the best way to do this is to fetch the chat list order from the api ,.. so that later if you want to modify this you can do this easily without updating/uploading APK

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Array.sort on your Chats array.

So you will have something like

```js
sortChats() {
  return this.Chats.sort((b, a) => new Date(b.lastModifiedDate).getTime() - new Date(a.lastModifiedDate).getTime())
}
```

And you can call your function like that

```html
 <ion-list  *ngFor = "let chat of sortChats()">
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do this in my .html file because it's there where I'm getting the list and not in the .ts file